# how to connect multiple databases on a single server with JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm trying to access data in multiple databases on a single running instance. the table structures of these databases are all the same; As far as I know, create a new connnection using jdbc is very expensive. But the connection string of jdbc require format like this
`jdbc:mysql://hostname/ databaseName`, which needs to specify a specific database.
So I'm wondering is there any way to query data in multiple databases using one connection?

[image: Multiple databases on a single running instance]

Comment: Read up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593647/how-to-create-multiple-database-connections-for-different-databases-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL documentation is badly written on this topic.

The [`SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) page refers to the [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) page for how a table name can be written, even if you don't use `JOIN` clauses. The [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) page simply says **`tbl_name`**, without further defining what that is. There is even a comment at the bottom calling this out:

> This page needs to make it explicit that a table reference can be of the form schema_name.tbl_name, and that joins between databases are therefore posible.

The [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) page says nothing about qualifying names, but does have a sub-page called [Identifier Qualifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html), which says that a *table column* can be referred to using the syntax `db_name.tbl_name.col_name`. The page says nothing about the ability to refer to *tables* using `db_name.tbl_name`.

But, if you can refer to a *column* using `db_name.tbl_name.col_name`, it would only make sense if you can also refer to a *table* using `db_name.tbl_name`, which means that you can access *all* your databases using a single `Connection`, if you're ok with having to qualify the table names in the SQL statements.

---

As mentioned by @MarkRotteveel in a comment, you can also switch database using the [`Connection.setCatalog(String catalog)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog(java.lang.String)) method.

This is documented in the [MySQL Connector/J 5.1 Developer Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html#idm139753552581488):

> **Initial Database for Connection**
>
> If the database is not specified, the connection is made with no default database. In this case, either call the `setCatalog()` method on the Connection instance, or fully specify table names using the database name (that is, `SELECT dbname.tablename.colname FROM dbname.tablename...`) in your SQL. Opening a connection without specifying the database to use is generally only useful when building tools that work with multiple databases, such as GUI database managers.
>
> **Note:** Always use the `Connection.setCatalog()` method to specify the desired database in JDBC applications, rather than the `USE database` statement.

Comment: You can also switch between databases by using `Connection.setCatalog(..)`; it might make life easier in some situations.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I haven't tried with MySQL, but are you sure it's [`setCatalog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog(java.lang.String)) and not [`setSchema()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setSchema(java.lang.String))?

Comment: See the implementation: [`ConnectionImpl.setCatalog`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java#L4869) and [`ConnectionImpl.setSchema`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java#L5439). See also the comment on `setSchema` that says _"until we flip catalog/schema, this is a no-op"_. Databases in MySQL seems to be a mix of catalog (stored separately) and schema (handling in queries).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks. Added `setCatalog` to answer.

Comment: Funny, I was looking for that quote you added, but I couldn't find it :).