# How to connect different DB based on the user input obtained by the REST service in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jdbc, informix

I need to create the application which connects to the different DB's based on the input from the user. What is the best solution to achieve this? I did search on Google but I failed to find the resources.

Answer (score -1):

You clearly haven't put much effort into searching. There are multiple solutions, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/10593773.
If you were to use Spring, I'd recommend this: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.