# How to Retrieve Data from Two Different MySQL Database using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How to retrieve data from two different MySQL database in a single query using jdbc?

```
SELECT 
      a.`driver_id`,
      a.`state`, 
      a.`lat`, 
      a.`long`, 
      MAX(a.`time_stamp`) AS timestamp,
      b.vehicle_type 
 FROM `rl_driv_location` AS a, `rl_driver_info` AS b 
 WHERE a.`state` = 1 AND a.`driver_id` = b.`user_id` 
       AND b.`vehicle_type` = '"+ cartype +"'  
 GROUP BY driver_id
```

- location database having the `rl_driv_location` table.
- core database having the `rl_driver_info` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the name of the databases where you want to retrieve data. See below.

```
SELECT 
      a.`driver_id`,
      a.`state`, 
      a.`lat`, 
      a.`long`, 
      MAX(a.`time_stamp`) AS timestamp,
      b.vehicle_type 
 FROM location.`rl_driv_location` AS a, core.`rl_driver_info` AS b 
 WHERE a.`state` = 1 AND a.`driver_id` = b.`user_id` 
       AND b.`vehicle_type` = '"+ cartype +"'  
 GROUP BY driver_id
```

Comment: how to modify the db url : static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/core";

Comment: Read this one, it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491729/java-connecting-to-multiple-databases